# Codebird.js and answer tweet

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm try to answer a specified tweet, but by my code I can only post a new tweet without associate it in reply to specified tweet. Seems as parameter in_reply_to_status_id_str is not recognised.

```
 var param={

                     "in_reply_to_status_id_str":id_str,
                     "status":"prova ciao",

             };

             console.log(param);
               cb.__call(
                     "statuses_update",
                    param,
                    function (reply) {
                    //gestire rate limit error 429
                     console.log(reply);
                     return reply;

                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `in_reply_to_status_id` - you don't need the `_str` at the end.

See the [Twitter Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update).

For example

```
var param={
   "in_reply_to_status_id":id_str,
   "status":"prova ciao",
};
```

Comment: I've tried without _str but nothing. And with javascript in_reply_to_status_id goes in overflow so you must use _str if you want effective number. @Terence eden

Comment: Yes, you need to use `in_reply_to_status_id_str` to get the value, but you pass it back to Twitter as `in_reply_to_status_id`

Comment: I don't understand, can you show me an example?Please. @terence eden

Comment: See the example I've just added.

Comment: You are the best! @terence eden